# mocha wait for db connection before running tests

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Basically to run the tests, I need the database connection to MongoDb to be ready. The database manager has a connect method to get a connection and a get method to get a reference to that connection. The connect method is supposed to be called only once, at startup. This design works fine when running the app because the app starts only if the connect method has been called and returned a connection.

The database manager using mongo native (no mongoskin, no mongoose) (database.js):

```
var config = require('../config')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

var connection = null

module.exports.connect = function () {
  return MongoClient.connect(config.mongodb.uri + config.mongodb.db)
    .then(function (db) {
      connection = db
    })
}

module.exports.get = function () {
  if (!connection) {
    throw new Error('Call connect first!')
  }
  return connection
}
```

Start the app:

```
var db = require('./services/database');
db.connect()
  .then(function() {
    logger.info("mongodb is running");
    require('./main')
  });
```

In the application, there are service modules and repository modules. The service modules require repository modules when they have to use the database. I have a BaseRepository module where I define the common queries findOne, findAll, etc. For all the MongoDb collections I have a specific repository that inherits from the BaseRepository. In the constructor, I set the collection by calling the database connection.

It means that when a service module which has a dependency on a repository module, the database connect method has to be called. This is the issue because I don't know how to start all the tests after the call to that connect method. **I am open to suggestions if you think it's a design flow.**

A test:

```
var usersService = require('../../services/rest/UsersService');
describe('IT Test', function () {
})
```

The service:

```
var usersRepository = require('../dao/UsersRepository');
```

The repository:

```
var db = require('../database');
var BaseRepository = require('./BaseRepository');
var util = require('util');

util.inherits(UsersRepository, BaseRepository);

function UsersRepository() {
    this.collection = db.get().collection('users');  // <====== The connect method has not been called yet
}
```

The base repository:

```
function BaseRepository() {
    this.collection = undefined;
}

BaseRepository.prototype.findOne = function (filters) {
    return this.collection.findOne(filters)
}
```

Comment: How do you call `connect` in tests? Do you have `before` hook?

Comment: I don't because I need to call it only once and then start all tests. Even if I call the `connect` in the `before`, it won't solve the issue since the issue is triggered by the `require(service) -> require(repository) -> constructor` calls the `get` whereas the connect has not been called. The `before` is called after the `require`.

Comment: You could move the code (`this.collection = db.get().collection('users');`) from repository constructor to a new `init` method, and call this method in `before` hook in test module. So you will have one global `before`, with calling `db.connect` and `before` in each test module for repo initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a wrapper for all the tests

```
'use strict'
var logger = require('../services/logger')()
var db = require('../services/database')

describe('All tests wrapper', function () {

  it('should pass', function () {
    return db.connect()
      .then(function () {
        logger.info('MongoDB is running')
        require('./agenda/AgendaJobsIT')
        require('./dashboard/DashboardsServiceIT')
        require('./twitter/TwitterServiceTest')
        require('./authentication/TokenServiceTest')
      })
  })

})
```

Comment: when you are closing database connection?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is mocha `--delayed` switch. mocha doc says

> If you need to perform asynchronous operations before any of your suites are run (e.g., for dynamically generating tests), you may delay the root suite. Run mocha with the --delay flag.

For example, use mocha in this way `mocha --recursive --exit --delay --ui tdd tests.js` and `--delayed` enable you to trigger running the root suite via calling `run()` explicitly.

```js
const fn = async x => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1500, 2 * x);
  });
};

(async function() {
  const z = await fn(3);

  suite("won't run until run() executes", () => {})

  run();
})();
```

For more information, please read https://mochajs.org/#delayed-root-suite.